# c++ vector using push_back

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, int

I noticed that if I use push_back to insert ints in the vector, I get an answer off by 1 but If I insert integers into my vector by vector[0] i get the right answer. My question is, is push_back doing more then just inserting my integer into the vector?

```
#include<vector>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

typedef vector<int> vi;

class KeyDungeonDiv2 {
public:

    int countDoors(vi doorR, vi doorG, vi keys)
    {
        int r = keys[0];
        int g = keys[1];
        int w = keys[2];
        int numdoors = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < doorR.size(); i++) {
            if(r >= doorR[i] && g >= doorG[i])
                numdoors++;
            else if (r < doorR[i] && g >= doorG[i]) {
                if(r + w >= doorR[i]) {
                    numdoors++;
                }
            }
            else if(r >= doorR[i] && g < doorG[i]) {
                if(g + w >= doorG[i]) {
                    numdoors++;
                }
            }
            else if (r < doorR[i] && g < doorG[i]) {
                if(w >= (doorR[i] - r ) + (doorG[i] - g)) {
                    numdoors++;
                }
            }
            else if(doorR[i] == 0 && doorG[i] == 0)
                    numdoors++;
        }
        return numdoors;
    }
};

int main()
{
    vector<int> redDoors (4);
    redDoors[0] = 2;
    redDoors[1] = 0;
    redDoors[2] = 5;
    redDoors[3] = 3;

    vector<int> greenDoors(4);
    greenDoors[0] = 1;
    greenDoors[1] = 4;  
    greenDoors[2] = 0;  
    greenDoors[3] = 2;  

    vector<int> keys (3);
    keys[0] = 2;    
    keys[1] = 3;    
    keys[2] = 1;    

    KeyDungeonDiv2 d;
    cout << d.countDoors(redDoors,greenDoors,keys) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

----vs.----

```
vector<int> redDoors (4);
redDoors.push_back(2);
redDoors.push_back(0);
redDoors.push_back(5);
redDoors.push_back(3);

vector<int> greenDoors(4);
greenDoors.push_back(1);
greenDoors.push_back(4);    
greenDoors.push_back(0);    
greenDoors.push_back(2);    

vector<int> keys (3);
keys.push_back;
keys.push_back(3);  
keys.push_back(1);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `vector<int>::push_back` method will always add to the vector, so when you use the `push_back` method, you're essentially increasing the size of the vector by one.

The constructor accepting a `size_t` object is setting the initial size of the vector, but populating it with default constructed objects.

So what you're doing is this:

```
vector<int> redDoors(4);
// redDoors = [ 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 ]

redDoors.push_back(2);
// redDoors = [ 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 2 ]


redDoors.push_back(0);
// redDoors = [ 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 2 | 0 ]

// ... and so on...
```

What you need to do is simply use the default constructor for your vectors. e.g.

```
vector<int> redDoors;
```

And if you need the optimization, you can use the `reserve` method to pre-allocate memory, which is what I assume you were trying to do.

Comment: So, if I need to find "what I added last time", I just check for redDoors[(redDoors.size()-1)] if it was constructed empty?

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik - Assuming that you used the `push_back` method to add the item to the vector, you can do what you suggested. Just be sure the check that your vector isn't empty first ;-)

Answer (score 3):

In the 2nd one you are creating vectors of a certain size. You are then using push_back. This is inserting the value to the end of the vector. The vector keys starts out with size 3, then when you do the 3 push_back calls the vector will have 6 elements.

Don't initialize the vectors to have a starting size. For the vector keys do this:

```
vector<int> keys;
```

You can then use

```
keys.push_back(5);
```

to insert data into the vector.

Answer (score 3):

The `push_back()` insert elements into the container. To get the same result as setting the size in the constructor and then setting the value you need to construct the initial vectors as empty, e.g.:

```
std::vector<int> redDoors;
```

Answer (score 1):

Push_back inserts an element in the end of the vector. But if the vector is full, it allocates new memory with increased capacity and copies the vector to new memory. 
But you are creating your vectors with initial sizes. You need to create them without these initial sizes as below

```
std::vector<int> foo;
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`push_back`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) method **appends the given element value to the end of the container.**

The [`constructor`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) of the type `explicit vector( size_type count );` **constructs the container with count value-initialized** (default constructed, for classes) instances of T. No copies are made.

So when you do :

```
vector<int> redDoors (4); // Create a vector of 4 ints initialized at 0
redDoors.push_back(2);    // Adds 2 at the end
redDoors.push_back(0);    // Adds 0 at the end
redDoors.push_back(5);    // Adds 5 at the end
redDoors.push_back(3);    // Adds 3 at the end

// Result :
// [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 5, 3 ]
```

If you want the same behaviour as when you access your vector with the [`operator[]`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at), just do :

```
vector<int> redDoors;     // Just create a vector
redDoors.push_back(2);    // Adds 2 at the end
redDoors.push_back(0);    // Adds 0 at the end
redDoors.push_back(5);    // Adds 5 at the end
redDoors.push_back(3);    // Adds 3 at the end

// Result :
// [ 2, 0, 5, 3 ]
```